# Operator in function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-operators, orlicz-spaces

Suppose I define the integral Operator $T:L^{\phi}(X)\to L^{\psi}(X)$ by $(Tf)(x)=\int_{X}K(x,y)f(y)d\mu$

Comment: Introduce a factor $\frac{|X|}{|X|}$ in the appropriate places to get into the situation of a probability measure. The rest seems fine.

Comment: I think we have to introduce this factor before using Jensen's inequality. Is this correct? If yes can you please tell me how the expression will be when we take this factor in account.

Comment: When you pull the $\Phi$ passt the integral put a $\frac{|X|}{|X|}$ infront of the integral before pulling in (the $\frac1{|X|}$ pulls out, the other term remains inside). In the end you shold get $\int_X\psi(\beta |T....|) \leq \frac{C}{|X|}\int\int\Phi(\beta |X| M |f(y)) $

Comment: but how can we directly take |X| out of the convex function $\Phi$? I mean we had $\Phi(\beta M \frac{|X|}{|X|}\int_{X}|F(y)|d\mu)$ then if we apply the jensen's inequality then $\Phi$ will go inside but how $\frac{1}{|X|}$ is coming out?

Comment: It becomes part of the measure

Comment: Thank you for the reply but can you please explain it more elaborately that will be very helpful. I am having a bit issue while changing the measure to apply Jensen's inequality. Thanks.

Comment: Let $\mu‘=\frac{1}{|X|}\mu$. You cannot apply Jensens inequality to $\mu$ because it is not a probability measure, but you can apply it to $\mu‘$. Absorb to 1/X into the measure so you can appl y Jensen. I cannot write it any more detailed because I am on a train.

Comment: Thank you. One more question I have is it possible to show that $Tf\in L^{\Psi}(X)$ without assuming the condition $\Psi(x)\leq C\Phi(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets show that $Tf\in L^\Psi$ without using the assumption that $\Psi(x)\leq C \Phi(x)$. First note that any $f\in L^\Phi$ is also in $L^1$, this can be seen as follows:

Let $f\in L^\Phi$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Phi(x)}x=\infty$ and $\Phi(x)$ is convex there is some $r>0$ so that $\Phi(x)>x$ for all $x>r$. Denote with $X_+ = \{ x\in X\mid |f(x)|>r\}$, then
$$\int_X|f| = \int_{X^+}|f|+\int_{X\setminus X^+}|f| \leq \int_{X^+}|\Phi(f)|+|X|\cdot r<\infty.$$

With this in hand let $|K|:=\sup_{x,y}|K(x,y)|$, then $|Tf (x)| \leq |K| \int |f|$ and so:
$$\int_X \Psi(|Tf|)\leq |X|\, \Psi(|K|\int_X|f|)<\infty.$$